# Same proc times forever to execute in test server

Tags: sql-server

Even though Im running the exact same stored procedures in the test server they are usually at least 5x slow to execute.Using local variables helps speed up things so i guess parameter sniffing is one of the problems.Another problem is that stored procedures misses cache 75% of the time.When I run the profiler I see a cache miss, then a long wait, then another cache miss, another long wait then cache insert.then the procedure starts executing.Any suggestions?

Comment: >>> cache miss<<< can be caused by non qualified sp calls, I mean, do you always use the SCHEMA when calling your sp?

Comment: The reason of recompilation can be found in Profiler: https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2013/02/19/find-the-reason-for-recompilation-using-sql-server-profiler

Comment: >>>Even though Im running the exact same stored procedures in the test server they are usually at least 5x slow to execute<<< Does your test server have the same configuration? Same memory, same CPU number, same threshold for parallelism? Did you compare the PLANS from prod vs from test env?

Comment: im calling dbo.procname, i selected everything on profiler and Im seeing cache miss x2 then cache insert, no recompile

Comment: Ok, so it's not a reason. there can be other 23 reasons, I gave you a link above to how to see the Type of recompilation using Profiler, get the reason from there

Comment: Does your test server has less RAM per chance?